# How to compose a link (`href`) in an Odoo 10 view

Tags: odoo-10

I have a regular view in my views folder with the `model=` set etc. I am displaying fields with no issues. I just just need to compose a link and to complete this, all I need is the current record ID then hopefully I can do something as simple as this:

`<a href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id={{ id }}">Report</a>`

Unfortunately the [views documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html) only tells me how to use fields which is not compatible with what I need.

My understanding is that any regular view is a QWeb view thats really in a `<template>` tag, so according to [this QWeb documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html) I tried this:

`<a href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id=t-esc="id"'>Report</a>` and

`<a t-attrf-href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id=#{id}'>Report</a>` and

`<a t-attrf-href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id=#{model.id}'>Report</a>` and

`<a t-attrf-href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id=#{record.id}'>Report</a>`

and about a dozen other things and nothing seems to work.

(just so you don't ask, yes I am updating the module before checking the result in the view)

I would prefer not to use `t-attf-href` when I could simply use `href`. A pointer to specific documentation would be great.

Comment: I also saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492575/how-to-use-if-in-odoo-template-language .. but does not work, probably because its Odoo-8 specific (according to the tag)

Comment: I've also tried it with the `<template>` / `<templates>` tag and without

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `<a t-att-href="('/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id=%s' % id)">Report</a>`, which is basically a string replace - I can't tell for v10, but this does the trick in v12 though.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
<a t-attrf-href="/rpt/the-report-for-widget?id={{id}}'>Report</a>
```